# Search Url in google gives index of

Tags: .htaccess

The result of the research with the domain gives index of
Thank you

[image]

The structure

-- css
-- fonts
-- fr
-- images
-- js
-- nl
.htaccess

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://*****.be/fr/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://*****.be/fr [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://*****.be/nl [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when a user requests the document root (and they don't have a language preference for `fr` or `nl`)? You can prevent the "index of" by disabling directory indexes, but then you'd get a 403 Forbidden... so you either need to put some content there OR implement a language picker OR redirect the request OR something else?

Comment: Is it possible to redirect to http: //*****.be/fr when a user requests the document root and also whitout content or language picker
How can I disabling directory indexes. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the "Index of ..." page indexed because you have directory indexes enabled *and* you have no content on that URL for when a user accesses your site without a preference for `fr` or `nl` languages.

To disable directory indexes add the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

However, that won't necessarily resolve your problem, as it will cause a 403 Forbidden to be served instead. Although that will prevent the URL from being indexed and your file structure getting exposed.

> Is it possible to redirect to http: //*****.be/fr when a user requests the document root

To *default* to that URL you can add another directive at the end of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Default non-fr and non-nl users that request the document root
RewriteRule ^$ http://*****.be/fr/ [L,R=301]
```

Note that since `/fr` appears to be a physical directory then you should include a trailing slash after `/fr` on the target URL, otherwise mod_dir is going to issue *another* redirect to append the trailing slash. This applies to your existing directives as well.

Comment: For the inspection of the url in Google Search Console, Is it necessary that I fill in each url or http: //****.be/ is sufficient

Comment: If by "each url" you mean the variations of HTTP, HTTPS, www and non-www then [Google does recommend verifying all those versions](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/02/announcing-domain-wide-data-in-search.html). However, GSC does also support [domain properties](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592) as well, that combine all site traffic from all protocol/hostname variations (requires DNS record validation).

Comment: By different url, I meant http: //*****.be/fr and http: //*****.be/nl

Comment: That's up to you. By verifying both properties it will allow you to report on each separately which could be desirable.